# What could change the umask of an existing process?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, umask

The objective is to understand what could change the umask of an already running process and recommendations on how to track down what could be causing the change.

A HUGE process is started which is part of a much larger "startup" process. This process is a large Java process which does significant JNI calls as well as some file i/o and the creation of directories.

Within a shell script is a loop that greps the /proc//status for "umask" value for this process.
As the umask value scrolls by, you can actually watch the value change.

```
007
007
113
113
113
007
113
113
007
```

It mostly flips between 2 values.

The Platform is Linux and uses Corretto 11.

**Questions :**

1 - Is it possible for Process A to change the umask value of Process B? If so, what command would be used? I can check if that command is being used.

2 - Is it possible for a procedure/function/JNI call within this HUGE process to changes the umask of the its own process? If so, what command would be used? I can check if that command is being used.

3 - What other calls should I search for that could be changing the umask value of this specific procedure?

4 - Any recommended tools to use for monitoring what is causing the umask change?

Comment: There is a `umask()` system call that you could probably trace using `strace`. Making sense of the trace output might be non-trivial, however, particularly if it's a JVM.

Comment: In the ordinary course of events, process A cannot change the umask setting for process B.  Debuggers are not necessarily "ordinary".  Yes, it is perfectly feasible to for a process (any process) to change its umask setting.  Indeed, the code seems to want to ensure no execute permission on some file creation operations (it probably isn't for directories since 0113 prevents the owner from accessing files in a directory).  The only plausible call that I'm aware of for changing the umask is [`umask()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/umask.html).  Tracing? `strace` or …

Comment: Run `strings -a` on all the shared libraries linked into the executable and look for `umask`, then disassemble any suspect library.  You can also use `LD_PRELOAD` to interpose on calls to the `umask()` function and have your interposing function dump things like thread id and a stack backtrace to a log file.

Comment: Note also that you and all the developers on this project have now learned two lessons:  **NEVER** depend on the process umask setting to set your file permission bits, and **NEVER** change the process umask setting because it impacts the entire process.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the "strings -a" attempt did not return any values.

Comment: Have you tried attaching a native debugger to the afflicted process and putting a breakpoint on the umask syscall? That will either tell you what native code does it, or point you to a JNI function that corresponds to a Java function you can break on with a Java debugger.

Comment: Unable to find any umask call being made in the code which is really adding to the confusion.

Comment: Which is why you need to let the debugger find the call *for you*.